# Как правильно удалить php модуль в centos?

Tags: php, linux, apache, bash

Centos 6.
Решил обновить на сервере версию php c 5.6 до 7.

1) Удалил с помощью  yum remove php*

2) Подключил репозиторий

3) Установил все модули версии 7.0, проверил php -v, вроде все было ок.

4) Заметил, что apache подключал версию 5, обновил mod_php

5) Решил не останавливаться(все из-за php-ml), установил 7.2, все пошло не очень - httpd не перезапустился, memcached не установился.

6) Откатился до 7.1 при этом в том же phpmyadmin версия 7.2. Все жутко лагает, хотел получить производительность, получил ее отсутствие.

Как мне все лучше сделать? Что возможно я делал не так? Хочу удалить все, что связано с php, заново его установить, получить обещанную производительность версии > 7.1.

Comment: это ж вы с каких-то «левых» сайтов берёте пакеты. вот на этих «левых» сайтах и читайте инструкции. там должно быть всё подробно написано. а если не написано, не пользуйтесь «левыми» сайтами.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Ну так-то да... просто не от хорошей жизни это. В официальных репозиториях до сих пор PHP5.4 лежит, потому и приходится на сторону ходить.